# scikit- DBSCAN giving error on clustering (x.y) co-ordinate points

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to computer ORB descriptors for an image and cluster them *spatially*. I was trying to use DBSCAN in scikit

```
detector = cv2.ORB(500)
orb_kp = detector.detect(gray,None)
# compute the descriptors with ORB
kps, descs = detector.compute(gray, orb_kp)
img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(gray,kps,color=(0,255,0), flags=0)
#extract the x,y points from the list (since kp contains various other attribs) 
pts = (p.pt for p in kps)
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples=5).fit(pts)
```

but I get this error:

`float() argument must be a string or a number`

so I tried : 
 `pts = (int(p.pt) for p in kps)`
and 
`pts = ([int(p.pt.x),int(p.pt.y)] for p in kps)`
and still get the same error.

I tried printing the pts in python but get this message:

`print pts
None
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x10fcab3c0>`

I am not sure how I can "cast" the `float` type for points into an `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK posting an answer for anyone who has the same issue:

`pts = (p.pt for p in kps)` is incorrect

it should be:
`pts = [p.pt for p in kps]`

Silly me!